# Connect network printer that contains spaces

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, dos

I use the following to map network printers

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to add: {0}", newPrinter);
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c start {0}", newPrinter);
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    if (Convert.ToInt16(row["IsDefault"]) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting Default");
        NativeMethods.SetDefaultPrinter(newPrinter);
    }
```

When the printer name contains a space it cuts it off before the space.
How can I get it to recognize the UNC of the printer with a space and have it connect?

Comment: On a side note. What does the command "start <printer name>" does?  Because I tried it on Windows 7 on all it does is open another command prompt window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/c start \"{0}\"", newPrinter);
```

Would that work?

Edit:

Or use WMI instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044827/4550393

Comment: If you are free to modify your code you could have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16044827/4550393 and use wmi instead?!