# Installing a printer using ManagementClass gives me an unidentified error in C#

Tags: c#, printing, installation

I am fairly new to C#.

I am trying to install a printer programatically using [this post I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040148/add-printer-to-local-computer-using-managementclass) however I get an exception here:

```
inputParam.SetPropertyValue("Print", "\\\\http://ip.of.my.server");
```

An exception of the type "System.Management.ManagementException" has been found in System.Management.dll.

Additional information: Not found.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace Printer
{
    class Installation
    {


        static public string addprinter()
        {
            ManagementClass win32Printer = new ManagementClass("Win32_Printer");
            ManagementBaseObject inputParam = win32Printer.GetMethodParameters("AddPrinterConnection");
                inputParam.SetPropertyValue("Print", "\\\\http://ip.of.my.server");

            ManagementBaseObject result = (ManagementBaseObject)win32Printer.InvokeMethod("AddPrinterConnection", inputParam, null);
            uint errorCode = (uint)result.Properties["returnValue"].Value;
            switch (errorCode)
            {
                case 0:
                    return ("Successfully connected printer.");

                case 5:
                    return ("Access Denied.");

                case 123:
                    return ("The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.");

                case 1801:
                    return ("Invalid Printer Name.");

                case 1930:
                    return ("Incompatible Printer Driver.");

                case 3019:
                   return("The specified printer driver was not found on the system and needs to be downloaded.");

            }
            return ("Unkown error.");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the form that calls the code, although I don't think the probleme is there:

```
private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Installation.addprinter());

            }
```

Comment: Where is the default in Switch case?

Comment: You did not copy the original correctly.  The name of the argument is "Name", not "Print".

Comment: @HansPassant. Thanks. It was that.